# Store private key and certificate of 3 subjects to keystore JAVA

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore

I want to save 3 certificates and 3 privatekeys to the keystore.

```
KeyStore store;
        PrivateKeyEntry CAprivKeyEntry = new PrivateKeyEntry(pair.getPrivate(), (X509Certificate[]) chain);
        TrustedCertificateEntry CAcertEntry = new TrustedCertificateEntry(caCert);
        PrivateKeyEntry interPrivKeyEntry = new PrivateKeyEntry(interPair.getPrivate(), chain);
        TrustedCertificateEntry interCertEntry = new TrustedCertificateEntry(interCert);
        PrivateKeyEntry subjectPrivKeyEntry = new PrivateKeyEntry(subPair.getPrivate(), chain);
        TrustedCertificateEntry subjectCertEntry = new TrustedCertificateEntry(subjectCert);


        try {
            store = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType);
            store.load(null, storePassword.toCharArray());
            store.setEntry("CA", CAprivKeyEntry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(storePassword.toCharArray()));  
            store.setEntry("CA", CAcertEntry, null);

            store.setEntry("Intermediate", interPrivKeyEntry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(storePassword.toCharArray()));  
            store.setEntry("Intermediate", interCertEntry, null);

            store.setEntry("Subject", subjectPrivKeyEntry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(storePassword.toCharArray()));  
            store.setEntry("Subject", subjectCertEntry, null);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(storePath));

            store.store(out, storePassword.toCharArray());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It brings the KeyStoreException: **Cannot overwrite own certificate** 
How can I fix this?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that the same alias can't contain both a private key entry and a trusted cert entry

Comment: Did your subject receive a signed certificate from a CA or do they have self-signed certificate? What are your `chain`, `interCert`, `subjectCert` and `caCert` variables?

Comment: changed the entry alias now it works. But I get a nonreadable output. How can I convert it in human readable format?